# How to send text from database to TTS without chang page

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Tts.java

```
public void onInit(int arg0) {
    Bundle dataBundle = Tts.this.getIntent().getExtras();
    speech = dataBundle.getString("IMSENS");
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
    tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
 }
```

Im_SensShow.java

```
public class Im_SensShow extends ListActivity {
    public void buttonGetClicked(View v){
    Cursor cc = cursor;
    Intent showSound = new Intent(Im_SensShow.this,Tts.class);
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("IMSENS",cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_IM_SENS)));
    showSound.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivityForResult(showSound,1);
}
```

I set tts to read a sentece from Im_SensShow.java and when I press the button in Im_SensShow.java page this progarm change to tts page and make sound

but actually I want it to send only sentence and doesn't change page (stay in Im_SensShow.java page)

I try to not declare .Tts in Manufest but it force close 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `tts.speak()` call in a `[onItemClick()][1]` listener.

You need to make sure that the TTS subsystem is already initialized (e.g. within `onCreate()` of your Im_SendShow activity).